# Autolayout and minium ios version

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I would like to know whether there is minimum IOS version for autolayout (like will it be ok on ios 4?). I am reading this https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html and it say it is included in xCode 5. Is there minimum ios version to use autolayout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iOS 6.0 is the minimum version. If you see, for example, the [`NSLayoutContraint` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/NSLayoutConstraint/NSLayoutConstraint.html) you'll see the version number information there.